# how can i open pdf generated by report viewer in new tab?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, reportviewer

**I did a code to create PDF and download it**

```
 protected void create_pdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streamIds;
    string mimeType = string.Empty;
    string encoding = string.Empty;
    string extension = string.Empty;
    string devinfo = "<DeviceInfo><ColorDepth>32</ColorDepth><DpiX>350</DpiX><DpiY>350</DpiY><OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
           "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
            "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
            "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
            "  <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>" +
             "  <MarginRight>0in</MarginRight>" +
             "  <MarginBottom>0in</MarginBottom>" +
           "</DeviceInfo>";

    // Setup the report viewer object and get the array of bytes
    ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
    viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Installments_Report.rdlc");
    DataView dv = new DataView();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dv = (System.Data.DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    dt = dv.ToTable();
    viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt));

    byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", devinfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);


    // Now that you have all the bytes representing the PDF report, buffer it and send it to the client.
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = mimeType;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Installments" + "List" + "." + extension);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); // create the file
    Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download
}
```

**Have any ways to open this PDF in a new tab or page ?**

*that's because i need to have button to direct print the report*

the suggestion that to open the pdf in new tap then user can print it

any other suggestion !!?

Thanks for the help!*

Comment: Use an html anchor with target="_blank" that redirects to a new page and in the new page's Page_Load generate the report?

Comment: okay but this code for download not to open the created pdf @PeetvdWesthuizen

Comment: @PeetvdWesthuizen i need to view pdf inside the browser window

Comment: to force open pdf change Content-Disposition Header form attachment to inline : 
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename.pdf

Comment: Nice @2GDev thank you :) what if i need to open it in new tap ? in your consideration i have alot of parameters in this page

Comment: You could save the byte[] in a session and use it on the new page maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**i have got answer**

1. Firstly You Need To create pdf file from report viewer and Save it
   somewhere on server
2. you need to save the file in unique name
3. After that use file stream to write from bytes to pdf file on your server path
4. path the file name by using query string to new page
5. in Page_Load qet the pdf file name from query string and open it

   ```
   protected void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   Warning[] warnings;
   string[] streamIds;
   string mimeType = string.Empty;
   string encoding = string.Empty;
   string extension = string.Empty;
   string devinfo = "<DeviceInfo><ColorDepth>32</ColorDepth><DpiX>350</DpiX><DpiY>350</DpiY><OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
          "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
           "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
           "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
           "  <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>" +
            "  <MarginRight>0in</MarginRight>" +
            "  <MarginBottom>0in</MarginBottom>" +
          "</DeviceInfo>";

   // Setup the report viewer object and get the array of bytes
   ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
   viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
   viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Installments_Report.rdlc");
   DataView dv = new DataView();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dv = (System.Data.DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
   dt = dv.ToTable();
   viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt));

   byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", devinfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
   // Now that you have all the bytes representing the PDF report, buffer it and send it to the client.
   string path =Server.MapPath("Print_Files") ;
   Random rnd = new Random();
   int month = rnd.Next(1, 13); // creates a number between 1 and 12
   int dice = rnd.Next(1, 7); // creates a number between 1 and 6
   int card = rnd.Next(9); // creates a number between 0 and 51
   string file_name = "Installments" + "List" + month+dice+card+".pdf"; //save the file in unique name 

   //3. After that use file stream to write from bytes to pdf file on your server path

   FileStream file = new FileStream(path + "/" + file_name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
   file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   file.Dispose();

   //4.path the file name by using query string to new page 

   Response.Write(string.Format("<script>window.open('{0}','_blank');</script>", "Print.aspx?file="+file_name));
    }
   ```

**in Page_Load qet the pdf file name from query string and Open PDF File in Web Browser**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
    string file_name = Request.QueryString["file"];
    string path = Server.MapPath("Print_Files/"+file_name);

    // Open PDF File in Web Browser 

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);
    if (buffer != null)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    }
 }
```

Done !!!
hope this code helpful to someone :)
Thanks!!!

Comment: It works fine till I didn't added sub-reports. anybody have idea how to handle sub-report as well in same scenario.

Comment: Thanks this works for me up until now 2023, aspx is kinda hard unlike reactjs hehehe

Comment: Thanks this works for me on my IIS of my laptop only, but when i deployed it on the server it is not working