# Connect SSRS to Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, reporting-services

I have an existing SSRS Report and a completely different Web API that I would like to have communicate. Basically I want the Web API to connect into the SSRS server, run a report, and then save the results in a PDF file. Is this even possible or would it be better to attempt to create the file on the fly using something like Microsoft Interop?

Comment: Would you be okay with using the ReportViewer object to run/get the report and save it as a PDF?  Like this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115986/how-can-i-open-pdf-generated-by-report-viewer-in-new-tab

Comment: I copied that code over but I'm getting missing reference errors on Warning[], Report Viewer, DataView, DataTable, SqlDataSource1, ReportDataSource, and Server. Any ideas on how to fix those?

Comment: You mean like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/accessing-the-soap-api?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Use the [ReportExecutionService.Render](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render) method. That link has the code you need.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to connect into my existing SSRS server using ReportExecutionService but for some reason my project doesn't let me reference that. I'm not missing anything that I can see. My project just doesn't like ReportExecutionService. So what I ended up doing is just going the long and difficult route of re-creating the report from scratch in C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop. It's definitely more difficult to do but it's my only option since no one has a clue why ReportExecutionService doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do many things through SSRS APIs but not everything
[checkout](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/SSRS/2.0#/)

You can achieve what you need with the help of URL access beside the APIs.

You need to use the following endpoints to reach your goal:
POST /Session (to login)
GET /Reports (to get the report path)

Then use [URL ACCESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access?view=sql-server-2017) to generate PDF path which is pretty much your:

```
{SSRS URL} / reportserver / {path} ?rs:Format=PDF
```